# Can I add an extra step to an iteration?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a function that is supposed to calculate x number of business days (excluding weekends and holidays) before or after the given date.

The problem is that when the last day falls on a weekend or a business day, it doesn't add an extra iteration...

```
SELECT afidb.dbo.AddBusinessDays(-21,'11/08/2016')
```

The above should be returning `2016-10-7`, but is returning `2016-10-10`. October 10th was a holiday, and the 2 days before it are weekend days.

I think that is because on the last iteration, `@bdays = 0` so it exits and doesn't add an extra step.

Am i wrong in this, or is there another issue going on?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Addbusinessdays] (
    @bDays INT -- number of business days to add sub.  
   ,@d DATETIME -- variable to hold the date you want to add or sub days to  
    )
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nDate DATETIME -- the working date  
        ,@addsub INT -- factor for add or sub   

    SET @ndate = @d

    IF @bdays > 0
        SET @addsub = 1
    ELSE
        SET @addsub = - 1

    WHILE @bdays <> 0 -- Keep adding/subtracting a day until @bdays becomes 0  
    BEGIN
        -- incr or decr @ndate  
        SELECT @bdays = CASE 
                WHEN (@@datefirst + Datepart(weekday, @ndate)) % 7 IN ( 0 ,1 ) -- ignore if it is Sat or Sunday   
                    THEN CASE 
                            WHEN @bDays = 0
                                THEN @bdays + 1 * @addsub
                            ELSE @bDays
                            END
                WHEN (
                        SELECT Count(*)
                        FROM dbo.tblholidays
                        WHERE holidaydate = @nDate
                        ) > 0
                    -- ignore if it is in the holiday table  
                    THEN CASE 
                            WHEN @bDays = 0
                                THEN @bdays + 1 * @addsub
                            ELSE @bDays
                            END
                ELSE @bdays - 1 * @addsub -- incr or decr @ndate  
                END

        SET @ndate = Dateadd(day, 1 * @addsub, @ndate)
    END

    RETURN Cast(@nDate AS DATE)
END
```

Comment: Tips: See [sign()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql). When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an extra check at the end of your while loop to make sure you don't land on a non-business day. After you SET @ndate = Dateadd(day, 1 * @addsub, @ndate), you have to check @ndate again. If it's a non-business day, increment or decrement @bdays so you enter the loop again.